# Start symfony web server when vagrant up

Tags: symfony, vagrant

I have a vagrant machine to deploy a Symfony application.

Nowadays I can:

- vagrant up
- vagrant ssh
- php /vagrant/app/console server:start 0.0.0.0:8000
- Access 10.10.10.10:8000 from browser's host

Provision script installs php, postgresql, and creates a database and the chema from doctrine.

**I want to run symfony web server automatically when the machine ups**. In this way, developer will not need to ssh to this vagrant machine to start this server.

**I tried to put "php /vagrant/app/console server:start 0.0.0.0:8000" in /etc/rc.local of the vagrant machine. But when I vagrant up, the server is not running :-(**

My vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.10"      
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh"
end
```

My provision.sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
apt-get update > /dev/null
apt-get install --assume-yes php5-cli
apt-get install --assume-yes php5-mcrypt php5-intl php5-pgsql php5-curl
apt-get install --assume-yes postgresql
sudo sed -i "s/^;date.timezone =$/date.timezone = \"Europe\/Madrid\"/" /etc/php5/cli/php.ini |grep "^timezone" /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
echo "client_encoding = utf8" >> "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf"
php /vagrant/app/console doctrine:database:create
php /vagrant/app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
sed -i "s/^# By default this script does nothing.$/php \/vagrant\/app\/console server:start 0.0.0.0:8000\\n#next free place/" /etc/rc.local |grep "^php" /etc/rc.local
```

Any idea how to have symfony's web server started on vagrant up?

Thanks!

Jordi

Comment: The Symfony web server is probably not your best bet for this. It would be much easier to configure/install a full web server like Nginx or Apache, preferably the same one you plan to use in your production environment.

Comment: Thanks @Oldskool, you are right, always better with an Apache (or Nginx). Symfony's web server choice was just to built this vagrant machine faster and simple. But I will try later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run it from vagrant, you can add the following in your `Vagrantfile`

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "php /vagrant/app/console server:start 0.0.0.0:8000", run: "always"
```

basically it will run the `php` command every time you run `vagrant up` wether you pass the `provision` flag or not.

If you want the vagrant user to run the command, you can add `privileged: "false"` to the command.

As others suggested, you might want to set up a real web server (apache, nginx) so it can be run from init

Comment: Thanks a lot @fhenri69. It solve my problem.
Why you think is better use a standard web server? It's just for development now. It can be faster using Apache?
Thanks again!

Comment: I dont think its faster with Apache but it will reflect your prod which is always good

Comment: Thanks @fhenri69. It's ok. If there is not more profit, for this project is enough with symfony's web server (at this moment at least) because its a prototype. Thanks for your feedback.